# Power series solution for nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am struggling to find a series solution for the initial value problem $y’=2y^2-3y+2$, $y(0)=y_0$.

By plugging in a power series, I have simplified and gotten $$\sum_{n\ge0}[(n+1)a_{n+1}-2(a*a)_n+3a_n]=2$$where $*$ is the Cauchy product. What is giving me trouble is the constant $2$ on the side, since I do not know how to avoid it and find a recurrence relation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The equation is separable. Are you specifically required to find a power series solution?

Comment: Make a substitution: let $w=y-2$ for instance.

Comment: Yes, the exercise is to solve it using power series.